# DOM listen/dispatch vs observe/notify patterns

Tags: javascript, dom, observable

What is the reason behind implementing observables instead of going on with already existing event based approach? From author's perspective it would be easier to add a listener to let's say "displace" event on specific elements instead of creating an intersection observer, adding indiviual elements to it and handle the callback with a list of entries for each observed element.